# Adding post excerpt into navigation menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

After each menu item, I want to add the page excerpt underneath it.

So if i have a menu that looks like this:

- Home
- About
- Contact

I want to get the page excerpt into the menu like this:

- Home

  - This is the home page excerpt
- About

  - This is the about page excerpt
- Contact

  - This is the contact page excerpt

Can I do this using the parameters in the `wp_nav_menu()` call? Or do I have to make a custom Nav Walker?

Answer (score 2):

[wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#source) calls [walk_nav_menu_tree()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_nav_menu_tree/#source) which calls the [Walker_Nav_Menu class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/#source).

There are a couple of filters you can hook into in those functions but I would take a look at the `nav_menu_item_title` filter in the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class. Here is the source:

```
/**
* Filter a menu item's title.
*
* @since 4.4.0
*
* @param string $title The menu item's title.
* @param object $item  The current menu item.
* @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
* @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
*/
$title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );
```

So you could write a filter like so:

```
function my_nav_menu_item_title( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    $title .= '<span class="excerpt">' . $item->post_excerpt . '</span>';
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'my_nav_menu_item_title', 10, 4 );
```

I haven't tested this but it should lead you in the right direction. I would inspect what is contained in `$item`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to kingkool68

```
function my_nav_menu_item_title( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) {
  $pid = $item->object_id;

  $text = get_the_excerpt($pid);

  $title .= '<span class="excerpt">' . $text . '</span>';
  return $title;

}
```